# Mysql select - performance drop after adding second join

Tags: mysql, sql

Following SELECT worked fine until I added second LEFT JOIN. Now the time to display table is 18s.

It works fine with both JOINS when I ommit group_concat and GROUP BY. Creating of view didn't help.
Between table1 and table2 is one to many relationship and because of that I need to use group_concat to have unique TICKETNO in every row.

Is it possible to write this query to execute it faster? Thanks.

```
SELECT table1.TICKETNO,
table2.STARTTIMESTAMP,
group_concat(table2.ACTION),
table1.COMPLETION,
table3.MEASURE
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.TICKETNO=table2.TICKETNO)
LEFT JOIN table3 ON (table1.ERRORCODE=table3.ERRCODE)
GROUP BY table1.TICKETNO
```

indexes:

```
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table1         |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | TICKETNO    | A         |       21894 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+



+-------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table             | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table2            |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | TICKETNO       | A         |       76110 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table2            |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | STARTTIMESTAMP | A         |       76110 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+


+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table3         |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | SPRAS       | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table3         |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | ERRCODE     | A         |        1138 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for my query:

```
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table1            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               | 21894 | Using temporary; Using filesort                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table2            | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | mydb.table1.TICKETNO               |     1 |                                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table3            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               |  1138 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
+------+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `table3` is not being used, so I would start by removing that from the query.

Comment: :) Good point, but it will be used.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ...in addition, questions about query performance also need the EXPLAIN statement for the given query.

Answer (score 1):

Although its slow, and you have not provided other specifics, I would just ask if you have indexes that can better help including:

```
table     index
table1    (ticketno, completion)
table2    (ticketno, action)
table3    (errcode, measure)
```

Comment: @culter, as mentioned in my answer.  Try creating covering indexes in these specific column orders and try your query, check performance. Let me know.  Each (field1, field2) should be a SINGLE index, not two individually.